# Data disappearing from file when changing encoding python

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

So I've got this script I'm pretty satisfied with although it has one flaw. When changing the encoding it suddenly removes all the data from the file. No idea why. Got comments in the code for each line what it does.

Rename file --> Move File --> Change Encoding --> Exec SQL SP --> Move change back name + timestamp

```
import os
import shutil
import glob 
import pyodbc
import os.path
import datetime
import codecs

#Defining function for SP
def SP():
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=serv400;DATABASE=db;Trusted_Connection=yes') 
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
query = "exec [PD_ABC_SP]"
cursor.execute(query)
cnxn.commit()

#Changing name, moving, importing and changing encoding for files in loop
destdir = '\\\\serv400\\f$\\BulkInsert\\Steve\\'
srcdir = '\\\\sesrv414\\Applications\\Prod\\IMP\\Phone\\'
inldir = '\\\\sesrv414\\Applications\\Prod\\IMP\\Phone\\Inlasta\\'
newfilename = 'Phone_Import_ABC.csv'
now = datetime.datetime.now()  #Adding datetime for timestamp
for oldfilename in os.listdir(srcdir): #Looping through files in directory
    if oldfilename.endswith(".csv"): #Changes filenames on files where name ends with csv
       os.rename(srcdir + oldfilename, destdir + newfilename) #Changing old path + filename
       codecs.open(destdir + newfilename, "w", encoding="utf-16") #switch encoding
       SP() #Executing the function for the stored procedure
       os.rename(destdir + newfilename, inldir + oldfilename + now.strftime("%Y%m%d")) 
        #Moving  back the files including the timestamp
```

Comment: The file is truncated when you do the `codecs.open(.., "w")`. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to change the encoding on the file before I import it to SQL through the stored procedure since we've got some swedish letters åäö in names that are not able to match properly in UTF-8 because of MS SQL server 2008

Comment: @Phillip forgot to tag you in previous comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`codecs.open(.., "w", ..)` opens a file for writing and truncates any previous content. It does not convert the file for you. For that, you'll need to open the file using its current encoding, read its contents and then re-open it in write mode using the target encoding and write the contents back. Something like

```
contents = codecs.open(old_filename, "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
codecs.open(new_filename, "w", encoding="utf-16").write(contents)
```

should work.